# fb-dimm without ecc

Tags: memory, ecc

Is it possible for FB-DIMM memory to be a memory without ECC, or every FBDIMM memory module is ECC?

ECC - is builtin memory errors correction.

FB-DIMM - is type of server memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly Fully-Buffered memory *can* be offered without ECC as the AMB would hide any functionality from the memory controller but given FB memory is generally much more expensive than most other memory types *why not* go for ECC at the same time and reap the benefit.

Comment: It sounds like theory, but what is in real life? I just checked online market and there are 405 FB-DIMM with ECC and no FB-DIMM without ECC. So, in real life there is no (or almost no) nonECC FB-DIMM, is it?

Comment: Your question says "Is it possible?" not "Does it exist?", to answer the second question would require huge amounts of work looking at every part from every memory manufacturer and even if none were found could be wrong the next day.

Comment: my question is "are all fb-dimm ecc-protected or not". While it is possible to fb-dimm to be nonecc, it is very unlikely.